# How to clean a string and leave in place only the first semicolon

Tags: java, regex, csv

I have this kind of list in CSV file:

```
    4231;"Swiss Federal Railways (SBB; CFF; FFS)"
    67;"Hershey Co; The"
```

My goal is to clean these strings and leave in place only the first semicolon:

```
4231; Swiss Federal Railways (SBB CFF FFS)
67; Hershey Co The
```

I tried to do that:

```
String[] companyDetails =
                    line.replaceAll("\"","").trim().split(";");
```

but it is not enough.

EDIT:
to be more clear, this is the code that I use:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/blue/IdeaProjects/matching/src/main/resources/company_list.csv"));

            // Creating a HashSet for holding Company object
            HashSet<Company> companyHashSet = new HashSet<Company>();

            String line;

            // Read to skip the header
            br.readLine();

            // Reading from second line
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] companyDetails =
                        line.replaceAll("\"","").trim().split(";");
```

Comment: I don't know if this is possible in Java (using regex alone) since its regex engine doesn't include certain tokens that other regex engines do. In other regex flavours you could use [`(?:^[^;\v]*;|\G(?!\A))[^;\v]*\K;`](https://regex101.com/r/X60Cba/1/).

Comment: You're not replacing the other semicolons yet. It's exactly the same protocol as replacing the speech marks, except you use a Regex that looks inside the speech marks for semi colons first, and then removes them

Comment: Maybe get a substring from the first semi-colon, then do your replaceAll method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

#### Java

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/X60Cba/3)

```
((?:^[^;\v]*;|\G(?!\A))[^;\v]*);
```

Replacement

```
$1
```

#### Other Languages (i.e. PCRE)

In other regex flavours, you could use the following regex, but Java doesn't support the token `\K` (reset the starting point of the reported match - any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match). This would use a replacement of an empty string instead of a capture group.

```
(?:^[^;\v]*;|\G(?!\A))[^;\v]*\K;
```

---

### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/tsGEpm)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "((?:^[^;\\v]*;|\\G(?!\\A))[^;\\v]*);";
final String string = "    4231;\"Swiss Federal Railways (SBB; CFF; FFS)\"\n"
     + "    67;\"Hershey Co; The\"";
final String subst = "$1";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
     4231;"Swiss Federal Railways (SBB; CFF; FFS)"
     67;"Hershey Co; The"
```

#### Output

```
     4231;"Swiss Federal Railways (SBB CFF FFS)"
     67;"Hershey Co The"
```

---

### Explanation

- `((?:^[^;\v]*;|\G(?!\A))[^;\v]*)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `(?:^[^;\v]*;|\G(?!\A))` Match either of the following

    - `^[^;\v]*;`

      - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
      - `[^;\v]*` Match any number of any character not present in the set (any character except semi-colon `;` or vertical whitespace)
      - `;` Match the semi-colon character `;` literally
    - `\G(?!\A)` Assert position at the end of the previous match
  - `[^;\v]*` Match any number of any character not present in the set (any character except semi-colon `;` or vertical whitespace)
- `;` Match the semi-colon character `;` literally

Comment: Great regex explanation! @OP: copy that explanation into your sorce code as a comment. Future readers will be thankful that they don't have to spend hours trying to understand the logic behind the regex.

Comment: @ctwheels: how to merge your result with my situation?

Comment: @StoreCode you would basically replace the `string` variable with `line`

Comment: @ctwheels: sorry but I can't
`br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/blue/IdeaProjects/matching/src/main/resources/company_list.csv"));

            // Creating a HashSet for holding Company object
            HashSet<Company> companyHashSet = new HashSet<Company>();

            String line;
  
            br.readLine();

            // Reading from second line
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] companyDetails =
                        line.replaceAll("\"","").trim().split(";");`

Comment: how merge your solution between mine

Comment: I can't actually test the Java code right now, but you would simply put my logic inside your while loop and then use your `line` variable instead of my `string` variable. This would then run regex against your string (`line`) instead of the hardcoded value I provide in my answer. Then you want to set `line` to the new value.

Comment: @ctwheels: I will try, thanks, but mine is not a simple String is an Array of String as you can see on my question edited. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

In java you could use the `split()` function: it breaks the string into an array everytime it find a pattern.
In your case:

```
    String source = "4231;\"Swiss Federal Railways (SBB; CFF; FFS)\"";
    String parts[] = source.split(";");
    String fullString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
        if (i != 0) fullString = fullString + parts[i];
    fullString = parts[0] + ";" + fullString;
```

And then build the final string as you want

Comment: Hi Marco, this is incorrect. My purpose is to maintain the first semicolon, no to replace all of them

Comment: In that way you separate the first string in pieces and then manipulate them. My was only a tip for a possible solution, I've seen ctwheels' answer and it is more elegant but also more complex, it depends on what you have to do.

Comment: Grazie Marco del tuo aiuto, proverò ad utilizzare il tuo metodo (forse sei italiano come me).
Thank you Marco for your help, I will try to use your method (maybe you are Italian like me)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the first occurrence of ; with a temporary string, do your changes, and revert the temporary part back to the semicolon.

```
String s = "4231;\"Swiss Federal Railways (SBB; CFF; FFS)\"";
s = s.replaceFirst(";", "~~~").replaceAll(";", "").replaceAll("\"", "").replaceFirst("~~~", "; ");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
4231; Swiss Federal Railways (SBB CFF FFS)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I have an error with this solution.

Comment: @StoreCode Can you post the error? It is working for me

Comment: it said that required java.lang.String[] but found: java.lang.String

Comment: In this example I didn't use split so the String remains as type String. The output isn't a String array. So instead of `String[] companyDetails = ...` you need `String companyDetails = ...`

Therefore:  `String companyDetails = line.replaceFirst(";", "~~~").replaceAll(";", "").replaceAll("\"", "").replaceFirst("~~~", "; ");`

Comment: but I can't, after that the achieve is to put into an hashSet, let me try

Comment: So are you just trying to get `Swiss Federal Railways` and add that into the HashSet?

Comment: Yes, I need to use scanner to do that.

Comment: I have more than one, I have 12000 lines not all the same

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll(";", "");
s = s.substring(s.indexOf('\"')+1, s.lastIndexOf('\"'));`